# How to extract the second instance of integer value in a string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a DataFrame with one column having values like `ABC_S22_F1, ABD_P23_H3,ABE_Q25_K3`.
When I do `df['col1'] = df['Column_Name'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)`, I get the first instance of Integer (i.e 22,23,25) in new column `col1`. I want `col2` to have second instance of integer having values 1 3 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) for extract all integers and then select second value of lists:

```
df['col1'] = df['Column_Name'].str.findall('(\d+)').str[1].astype(int)
print (df)
  Column_Name col1
0  ABC_S22_F1    1
1  ABD_P23_H3    3
2  ABE_Q25_K3    3
```

Comment: I leveraged @jezrael solution for my situation that is slightly different and could not make it work.  In the example below, the second number is 2 in "hello 10 world 2" but python is only returning 10.

df = pandas.DataFrame({"x": ["hello 10 world 2","5.21 hello","25 hello 30"]})

#return all the numbers 
df["x"].str.findall('(\d+\.*\\d+)')  

why it did not return the 2 in the first row?

Comment: @seakyourpeak - You can change regex `df["x"].str.findall(r'(\d*\.?\d+|\d+")')`

Comment: it did work.  Thanks.  Do you think df["x"].str.findall(r'\d*\.?\d+')  is sufficient and adding |\d+ is not needed.

Comment: @seakyourpeak - agree, you are right.